# Dynamic express.static() folder path

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an application that uses express.static to access some user information, and the routes logic are like this:

```
app.get('/principal',function(req,res,next){
    if(req.query.user=='admin'){
        next();
    }else{
        res.send("not allowed");
    }
});
app.use('/principal',express.static('/_site'));
```

But now I need it to all users, so should be something like that:

```
 var username = '';
 app.get('/principal',function(req,res,next){
        if(req.query.user){
            username = req.query.user;
            next();
        }else{
            res.send("not allowed");
        }
    });
    app.use('/principal',express.static(username+'/_site'));
```

I have a folder to every username, my express.static() keeps reading the username var empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to serve static files from the route handler to make it dynamic to the query username:

```
app.get('/principal',function(req,res,next){
    if(req.query.user){

        // serve static files for usename
        app.use('/principal', express.static(username +'/_site'));

        res.send("allowed");
    }else{
        res.send("not allowed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Only show a "allowed" page and not my /_site files. If i remove the res.send it loads forever

Comment: Yes it will show 'allowed', but if you call some file from `username +'/_site'` it will render it, for example let's imagine that you have a file called `style.css` inside some username directory , let us say `leonardo`, if you go to  `/principal/?user=leonardo`, express will set `./leonardo/_site` as static direoctory and then it will render `allowed`, now if you try to call route `/principal/style.css` express will render the file `style.css` located on  `./leonardo/_site`

Comment: Worked. But I needed to chagne the  'res.send("allowed");' to         res.sendfile(path, {root: '/_site'});.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with `express.static`. However, you could,

```
app.get('/principal', function(req, res){
    if(req.query.user){
        const username = req.query.user;
        const path = `${username}/boo.js`
        res.sendfile(path, {root: '/_site'});
    }else{
        res.send("not allowed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did it with my index.html file, but it don't load my CSS/JS files, only the rae html. I did it : const path = `${username}/index.html`